# SAPUI5 format a data from a format in a model with binding

Tags: xml, binding, sapui5

### Environement

Framework: SAPUI5 V1.38.39

### Question

For date in view from SAP UI5 it is possible to format the date from a date format such as :

```
<Text 
    text="{
      path:'HandlingUnitMultipleModel>PlannedDeliveryDate',
      type:'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime',
      formatOptions: { UTC:true, pattern: 'dd-MM-yyyy'} }" />
```

Would it be possible to directly bind a model dynamically for the pattern contained in a customized model (can be yyyy-MM-dd, dd-MM-yyyy, MM-dd-yyyy, MMM, dd yyyy, etc. from the user preference) and not from user location as :

```
<Text 
    text="{
      path:'HandlingUnitMultipleModel>PlannedDeliveryDate',
      type:'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime',
      formatOptions: { UTC:true, pattern: '{UserModel>/DateFormat}'} }" />
```

It doesn't work like it, but maybe there is a way to do that?
I know there is a possibility to use a formatter but I wished to know if it was another way by binding inside the binging.

Comment: Binding works only on ManagedObject properties (such as `text`) but not on other properties from plain object.

Answer (score 1):

UI5 does not support this, but you can implement by yourself

```
<Text text="{parts: [{path: 'HandlingUnitMultipleModel>PlannedDeliveryDate'}, {path: 'UserModel>/DateFormat'}], formatter: '.formatMyDate'}" />
```

```
function formatMyDate(date, format){
   //your formatting logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rather using the `DatePicker` with `ValueFormat`-property ?

Comment: DatePicker control is the way I enter the date in the first page, Text control is how the date is displayed in the table

Answer (score 0):

Use [sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime) instead of [sap.ui.model.type.DateTime](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.type.DateTime)

```
<Text 
    text="{
      path:'HandlingUnitMultipleModel>PlannedDeliveryDate',
      type:'sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime', //New type
      constraints: {
            displayFormat: 'Date', // ... only the date part is used [...] the time zone is UTC...
            nullable: false //if true, the value null is accepted
          } />
```

Comment: This was suggested in the beginning but apparently the app definitely needs to be able to define the pattern dynamically according to user's app setting (not according to user's locale setting from the browser by which UI5 would've determined the pattern automatically).